# How to filter by Azure Storage Account Container using KQL?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I've almost got the perfect KQL query! I'm just missing the ability to filter the Log Analytics Workbook by Storage Container.

**Issue:**

- The `ContainerName` column is calculated so I'm unsure how to use the `where` clause for filtering.

**Sample data:**

```
datatable(TimeGenerated: datetime, AccountName: string, OperationName: string, Uri: string )[
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:06.07), "stgtest", "CreatePathFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:06.08), "stgtest", "CreatePathFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:06.13), "stgtest", "LeaseFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:06.13), "stgtest", "LeaseFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.10), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.10), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.11), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.12), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.28), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.33), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.35), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.40), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.41), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.59), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.59), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.60), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.60), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.61), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.61), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.62), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.62), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.63), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.64), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.65), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.66), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.66), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.67), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.68), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.70), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test1.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.87), "stgtest", "FlushFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.89), "stgtest", "LeaseFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-1/subdir-1/test2.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.96), "stgtest", "CreatePathFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:07.97), "stgtest", "LeaseFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3.txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.29), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.29), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.29), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.30), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.31), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.32), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.32), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.60), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.64), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.65), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.65), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.68), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.70), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.70), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.72), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.72), "stgtest", "AppendFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:08.79), "stgtest", "FlushFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900",
datetime(2022-10-04 03:07:09.05), "stgtest", "LeaseFile", "https://stgtest.blob.core.windows.net:443/cont-2/subdir-1/test3txt?se=2022-10-06T18%3A40%3A10Z&sig=XXXXX&sp=rwl&spr=https&sr=c&sv=2021-04-10&timeout=900"
];
```

**Sample query:**

```
//==================================================//
// Set variables
//==================================================//
let varEventTime            = todatetime('2022-10-04 03:07:07.63');
let varLogStart             = varEventTime - 10m;
let varLogEnd               = varEventTime + 10m;
let varOperationNames       = dynamic([
                                'AppendFile', 
                                'CreateFilePath', 
                                'FlushFile', 
                                'LeaseFile']);
let varContainerNames       = dynamic([
                                'cont-1', 
                                'cont-2', 
                                'cont-3', 
                                'cont-4']);
//==================================================//
// Filter table
//==================================================//
StorageBlobLogs
| where
    AccountName             == 'stgtest'
    and TimeGenerated       between (varLogStart .. varLogEnd)
    and OperationName       has_any (varOperationNames)
//    and ContainerName       has_any (varContainerNames) // This is the issue
//==================================================//
// Create calculated columns
//==================================================//
| extend FilePath           = parse_path(tostring(parse_url(Uri).Path))
| extend ContainerName      = split(FilePath.DirectoryPath, '/')[1]  // Because ContainerName is calculated here
| extend FileName           = split(FilePath.Filename, "%2F")[-1]
//==================================================//
// Select columns
//==================================================//
| project
    TimeGenerated           = format_datetime(TimeGenerated, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'),
    AccountName,
    ContainerName,
    OperationName,
    FileName
//==================================================//
// Sort table
//==================================================//
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

Comment: Treating dynamic values as strings...  Assuming that an array has only a single element... There's work to be done here. Please supply a data sample + required results.

Comment: I edited the original post to have sample data. `Required results` would be results filtered by `ContainerName`'s listed in the filter query.

Comment: I'm unable to figure out why the `Uri` is not parsed in the Sample Data `extend FilePath, ContainerName nor FileName` columns. `Uri` is parsed in the `StorageBlobLogs` table.

Comment: It seems you are not only filtering, but also manipulating the data for displaying purposes. If that's the case, then you should add the require results.

Answer (score 0):

```
| where Uri has_any(varContainerNames)  // Filter for performance reasons. Might get false positives. 
| parse parse_url(Uri).Path with "/" container "/" *
| where container in (varContainerNames)
```